# How to implement two "views" in android softkeyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I managed to create a simple qwerty android keyboard with a [tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/learn-to-create-a-system-keyboard-on-android-95aca21b1e5f)

- I just edited the layout to be a qwerty keyboard. now I want to add a second keyboard "view" with around **50 Unicode characters** and have an option in the keyboard to switch between the **"views"** using a button. This is similar to the qwerty and symbols view of the default softkeyboards.
- I found [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) online but I am not sure how to use that (how to get the imeToken, should I somehow initialize both layouts first, I basically don't have any idea how to start)